# Can't run command Invoke-Command on server returning status 504, in powershell

Tags: powershell, proxy

I'm trying to run a remote powershell command using this command

```
 Invoke-Command -ComputerName myServer -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock{hostname}
```

However, the command returns the following error:

```
 Connecting to remote server myServer failed with the following error message : The WinRM client received an HTTP status code of 504 from the remote WS-Management service. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
```

I've compared the configuration of different machines and the only difference that I've encountered is

- In the non-working machine the server proxy is setup automatically, unlike the other machines that is set manually (however the machines do not communicate through a proxy server) List item
- When I run the command `winrm e winrm/config/listener` in cmd, the non-working machines returns an IPv6 IP, unlike the others that only return IpV4 IPs

Can these configurations have something to do with the invoke-command not working?

Comment: They could but this is probably going to be a better question for Super User or Server Fault. Troubleshooting the `winrm` connection itself is out of scope for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yes, 504 usually means the listener timed out. Try manually running `Enable-PSRemoting -Force` on the non-working machine since it should set the winrm listener to listen on any IP instead of just the ipv6 one. Alternatively, `Disable-PSRemoting; Enable-PSRemoting`. Or to set just the winRM portion, use `Set-WSManQuickConfig`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I've tried all of these and none of them seam to work. Most of them say that the winrm is already configured. I've also tried to configure the firewall and some policies and nothing

Comment: Does your listener still show only the IPv6 `Address`? If so, try and remove it directly with `Remove-WSManInstance -ResourceUri winrm/config/Listener`, then create a new one. It might require stopping the winrm service as well.